# BOOT_COMPLETED Broadcast Receiver Not Working in XOS-Android

Tags: broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, bootcompleted, chameleon

I am working on an app that sends the updates to users weekly once, even if the app is not opened. For this i am using Alarm Manager to send push notification to user, but when device gets rebooted the alarm manager loose all data. For this i added `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast receiver in my code for setting the Alarms again on reboot. It works fine but coming to the devices having Android XOS chameleon like Tecno c9,Tecno w3, Infinix Note3 `BOOT_COMPLETED` Broadcast Receiver doesn't work.

Is there any other thing that these Android XOS chameleon devices broadcast after reboot like here [HTC having customized boot complete broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525907/htcs-fast-boot-is-not-broadcasting-boot-completed-intent-nor-wiping-intents-f)

Comment: May i know the reason why one down voted my question please specify reason here. so, that i too know the reason/solution behind it.

Comment: I appreciate this question seeing that I've been using Tecno and Infinix devices to test which are bestsellers in my country. May I know how you eventually solved it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the problem was due to the HIOS,XOS flavors of Android maintaining the HiManager, XManager respectively in order to manage auto startup apps and other things. In which we need to manually enable our app to allow on start up.